# DATEDIF Report builder can i do an OR or where

Tags: sql-server, dataset, expression, datediff, reportbuilder

I am building a report where I need to display the number of days an item was with a customer in the chosen month.

@Month is set as a parameter and the report is filtered based on the month a user chooses.
I have DATEDIFF(d, dbo.Rental.StartDateTime, { fn NOW() }) + 1 AS [Days Live] however this isn't what I need.

A rental could start before the chosen month or part way through. It could end and any date in the chosen month or not have been ended at all. so for example if running the report for November (assuming i am now in December) i could have a rental that started (dbo.Rental.StartDateTime) 15th October and ended (dbo.Rental.EndDateTime) 11th November. I would need the field to say 11 however if there is no end date i would need it to say 30

I have formatted both fields to be dd/mm/yyy. The dataset is also doing various other things in terms of displaying the relevant records.

My entire dataset is below.

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT System_1.SystemTypeId, System_1.Id, System_1.CancellationCode, System_1.RentalId, Format(System_1.CreatedOnDateTime, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS [Assembled Date], 
                         Format(dbo.Rental.StartDateTime, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS [Start Date], DATEPART(month, dbo.Rental.StartDateTime) AS [Start Date Month], dbo.Rental.Revision, dbo.Rental.RentalNumber, dbo.Rental.RentalStatus, dbo.Customer.Name AS Customer, dbo.Site.Name AS Site, 
                         dbo.Location.Name AS Location, dbo.Rental.SpecialInstructions, DATEDIFF(d, dbo.Rental.StartDateTime, { fn NOW() }) + 1 AS [Days Live], dbo.SystemType.Description, Format(dbo.Rental.EndDateTime, 
                         'dd/MM/yyyy') AS [End Date], DATEPART(month, dbo.Rental.EndDateTime) AS [End Date Month]
FROM            dbo.SystemType INNER JOIN
                         dbo.System AS System_1 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Contract ON System_1.ContractId = dbo.Contract.Id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Customer ON dbo.Contract.CustomerId = dbo.Customer.Id ON dbo.SystemType.Id = System_1.SystemTypeId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Location INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Rental ON dbo.Location.Id = dbo.Rental.LocationId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Site ON dbo.Location.SiteId = dbo.Site.Id ON System_1.Id = dbo.Rental.SystemId
WHERE        (dbo.Rental.RentalStatus NOT LIKE 'PendingActivations') AND dbo.customer.ID = @Customer AND ((DATEPART(month, dbo.Rental.StartDateTime) = @Month) OR (DATEPART(month, dbo.Rental.EndDateTime) = @Month) OR ( (DATEPART(month, dbo.Rental.StartDateTime) < @Month) AND (dbo.Rental.EndDateTime IS NULL )))
ORDER BY System_1.Id
```

Comment: That isn't a dataset, that's a SQL statement. Don't forget, we can't run your SQL, we don't have access to your instance. Sample data, expected results, and your attempts will help us help you. Also, [3 part naming for columns is going to be deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should avoided. Stick to aliases your objects in the `FROM` and qualifying your columns with those.

Comment: Sorry this is my first post. I have put what i have tried and what i expect to see with an example. I cant include real data due to GDPR and  creating a mock up with all the variables would be time consuming. I work with other people who still wish to use 3 part naming so i am stuck as is for now. Apologise for doing it wrong I will look for help elsewhere.